# Composer runtime (0.18.2) is not compatible with client (0.17.6)

Tags: hyperledger-composer

I am trying to run [composer-sample-applicaions](https://github.com/hyperledger/composer-sample-applications)(Digital Property) but when I am trying to run npm test it is throwing an error: `Composer runtime (0.18.2) is not compatible with the client (0.17.6)`

Following is the complete log:

```
paradox@labrats:~/hyperledger/composer/github/composer-sample-applications/packages/digitalproperty-app$ npm test

> digitalproperty-app@0.0.7 test /home/paradox/hyperledger/composer/github/composer-sample-applications/packages/digitalproperty-app
> npm run bootstrapAssets && npm run listAssets && npm run submitTransaction


> digitalproperty-app@0.0.7 bootstrapAssets /home/paradox/hyperledger/composer/github/composer-sample-applications/packages/digitalproperty-app
> node cli.js landregistry bootstrap

info: [DigitalProperty-App] Hyperledger Composer: Digital Property console application
info: [DigitalProperty-App] Adding default land titles to the asset registry
error: [DigitalProperty-App] Error: Error trying to ping. Error: Composer runtime (0.18.2) is not compatible with client (0.17.6)
Command failed.
npm ERR! code ELIFECYCLE
npm ERR! errno 1
npm ERR! digitalproperty-app@0.0.7 bootstrapAssets: `node cli.js landregistry bootstrap`
npm ERR! Exit status 1
npm ERR! 
npm ERR! Failed at the digitalproperty-app@0.0.7 bootstrapAssets script.
npm ERR! This is probably not a problem with npm. There is likely additional logging output above.

npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
npm ERR!     /home/paradox/.npm/_logs/2018-03-26T09_35_58_193Z-debug.log
npm ERR! Test failed.  See above for more details.
paradox@labrats:~/hyperledger/composer/github/composer-sample-applications/packages/digitalproperty-app$
```

Any lead would be appreciated

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The runtime refers to the version of Composer that is installed on to the Peer with your Network - you can see this if you execute `docker ps -a` and you will see a container with a name such as `dev-peer0.org1.example.com-animaltracking-network-0.16.6...` this shows the Composer runtime version and the network name.

You have a couple of options:

1. Re-create your Fabric which will delete that container with the 18.2 runtime
2. Upgrade your client to 18.2

Different versions of Composer need different versions of Fabric - checkout this document which covers releases of Composer with their supported Fabric versions.

Answer (score -1):

Composer runtime and client must be on same version.
Best approach to solve this issue, execute following commands in order.

1. npm install -g composer-cli
2. npm install -g composer-rest-server